# Can I treat a letter as an integer in order to get a converted sum of a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a spreadsheet and I want to be able to filter by the converted sum of a cell.  For example, my cell has "5B" and I want it to evaluate to 6.  The same would be true for "2GG" evaluating to 4 and "RR" evaluating to 2.  Any letter equals 1 except for "X".  If there is an X in the cell, it should evaluate to "X".  I have searched all of the ways I can think of to see if this is even possible, but most of what I come up with are ways to convert numbers formatted as text to numbers formatted as numbers, which is not what I'm looking for.  I found some promising leads with LOOKUP, but they ultimately didn't fit my need.  Any help is appreciated.  I'm fairly inexperienced in both Excel and VBA.

Comment: Can your cell have more than one number? Like 23B = 24 or 2B3 = 6?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
Note : if you have the string like "ab2fdd5", the result will be incorrect.
Below is the solution from me.
I have the sample data like the following screen shot:
[image] 
To fulfill the request you want. The following macro is created.

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim MyOutputWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim SearchString As String
Dim SearchChar As String
Dim TestPos As Integer
Dim myStr As String

Sub StrNum()

Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

myStr = onlyDigits("3d1fgd4g1dg5d9gdg")
SearchChar = "X"

For currentRow = 1 To MyWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    SearchString = MyWorksheet.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value
    TestPos = InStr(1, UCase(SearchString), "X")
    If TestPos > 0 Then
        MyWorksheet.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value = "X"
    Else
        myStr = onlyDigits(SearchString)
        If myStr = "" Then
        myStr = 0
        MyWorksheet.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value = CLng(myStr) + Len(SearchString)
        Else
        MyWorksheet.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value = CLng(myStr) + Len(SearchString) - 1
        End If

    End If
Next
End Sub

Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    ' Variables needed (remember to use "option explicit").   '
    Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
    Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

    ' Initialise return string to empty                       '
    retval = ""

    ' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
    '   return string.                                        '
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Then return the return string.                          '
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

The output screen : 
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, Change the `rng` to look at which ever range you're concerned with.

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim c

With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, 1))
End With

For Each c In rng.Cells
    c.Offset(0, 1) = CalculateValue(c.Value)
Next c
End Sub
```

---

```
Function CalculateValue(s As String)
Dim l: Dim tmp
Dim i As Integer

If InStr(1, s, "x", vbTextCompare) Then
    tmp = "x"
Else

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        l = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(l) = True Then
            tmp = tmp + l
        Else
            tmp = tmp + 1
        End If
    Next i
End If

CalculateValue = tmp
End Function
```